# How can I fix quasar typescript file type error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, file, quasar

I'm trying to learn quasar with typescript.
I got a type error when I code file upload.

Below is my code. Type error occurs in the parameter of the form.append() method.
error message is

*"Argument of type 'Ref<File | null>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'."*

I have no idea how can I set the type of file variable.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, Ref } from 'vue';
import { QFile } from 'quasar';

const file: Ref<File | null> = ref(null);

const pickFile = (): void => {
  console.log(file.value);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', file);
  console.log(file.value);
};
</script>

<template>
  <q-file v-model="file" label="File Upload" @update:model-value="pickFile()">
    <template #prepend>
      <q-icon name="mdi-attachment"></q-icon>
    </template>
  </q-file>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FormData declares file as String|Blob, that means that whatever you pass in needs to be of the same type. You can initialise your ref like this:

```
const file: Ref<String | Blob> = ref("");
```

Also, when appending it to form data make sure you're passing in the value, not the whole ref

```
formData.append("file", file.value);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

FormData takes two types, `Blob` or `String`. But you are declaring file to be of type `null`.

```
// You should try initialize file as an empty string instead.
const file: Ref<String | Blob> = ref("");
```